# chef recipe wait for git clone to finish

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I've tried this a couple different ways, including creating a new recipe and notifying that recipe to run but I keep getting the same problem which is the **cloned repo directory doesn't exist before the `file` resource runs, so I get a fatal error.**

***my question is, can I make the git clone finish before the file resource tries to execute or is there a better way to do this?***

SN: what I'm trying to accomplish deals w/ new user environment setup - so after creating a new user i'm cloning down a bunch of config files from a git repo that will be deployed for that user.

```
  git "/home/#{user_id}/.myconfigs" do
    repository "https://url/to/repo"
    reference "master"
    user user_id
    group user_id
    action :checkout
    not_if "test -d /home/#{user_id}/.myconfigs"
    #notifies :run, "recipe[zsh_workstation::zshrc]"
  end

  file "/home/#{user_id}/.zshrc" do
    content IO.read("/home/#{user_id}/.myconfigs/.zshrc")
    owner user_id
    group user_id
    mode "0600"
    action :create_if_missing
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [Anatomy of a Chef Run](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Anatomy+of+a+Chef+Run)

At the moment chef compiles your file resource, git resource is not run (even is not started) yet, so file "/home/#{user_id}/.myconfigs/.zshrc" does not exist.

Possible workarounds:

1. This will copy the file after it is created by git using [FileUtils](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-i-cp).

   ```
   ruby_block "create /home/#{user_id}/.zshrc" do
     block do
       ::FileUtils.copy("/home/#{user_id}/.myconfigs/.zshrc", "/home/#{user_id} /.zshrc") unless ::File.exists? "/home/#{user_id}/.zshrc" 
     end
   end
   ```
2. Symlink instead of copy.

   ```
   link "/home/#{user_id}/.zshrc" do
     to "/home/#{user_id}/.myconfigs/.zshrc"
   end
   ```
3. Run git resource at compile stage.

   ```
   git "/home/#{user_id}/.myconfigs" do
     [...]
     action :nothing
   end.run_action :checkout
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much, these are all great answers!  I'm new to chef and ruby and this really helped!